Proof that connectedness of the complement of a graphic
I m looking for help proving the following statement:
Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces where in $Y$ is hausdorff and contains minimum 2 elements. Let $X$ be connected and for each $y \in Y$ is $Y\backslash\{y\} := \{y\}^c$ connected. Let $f: X \to Y$ be continuous map and define the graphic $\Gamma(f) := \{ (x,f(x)) \in X \times Y | x \in X\}$ of $f$. Proof now that the complement of the graph $(X \times Y)\backslash \Gamma(f) := \Gamma(f)^c$ is connected in $X\times Y$.
I came up with the following proof, and I would like to know if I m on the right track, or if something is missing or what I can do to make it more rigorous:
Proof
Define $\pi: \Gamma(f)^c \to X: (x,y) \mapsto x$ we know that $\pi$ is continuous. Assume now that $\Gamma(f)^c$ isn't connected, then there exist $W,V \subset X \times Y$ such that $W \cup V = \Gamma(f)^c$ and $\bar{W}\cap V = W \cap \bar{V} = \emptyset$. We know now that the for each $x \in S$ the fibre $\{x\} \times \{y\}^c$ is connected. We know noe from "Topology" by Munkres, Lemma 23.2. Page 149 that $\forall x \in X$ is $\{x\} \times \{y\}^c$ either completely in $W$ or completely in $V$. We define thus $A := \{ x \in X | \{x\} \times \{y\}^c \subset V\}$ and $B :=\{ x \in X | \{x\} \times \{y\}^c \subset W\}$. It is now evident that $A \cup B = X$ and that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Now because $\bar{V} \cap W = \bar{W} \cap V = \emptyset$ and $\pi(V) \supseteq A$ and $\pi(W) \supseteq B$ and $\pi$ was continuous, it follows that $\bar{\pi(V)}\cap \pi(W) = \bar{\pi(W)}\cap \pi(V) = \emptyset$ and thus $\bar{A} \cap B = \bar{B} \cap A = \emptyset$. But that means that there exists a separation $A,B$ of $X$, which cannot be, because $X$ was connected, thus there exists no separation $V,W$ of $\Gamma(f)^c$ and thus is $\Gamma(f)^c$ connected.
$\blacksquare$
I would really appreciate your help. thank you.

It seems correct. Some minor fixes can be done: first, you fix $y$ when defining $A$ and $B$, make sure that you explicitly mention that, and second, you must assume that $W,V$ are nonempty, and conclude that $A,B$ are nonempty. Otherwise, it is technically still possible that one of $A,B$ turns out to be empty, and then $X$ wouldn't have a separation.
Hope this helps. :>

Thank you for your help and the fixes ^^. I struggle sometimes with the details. Thanks again.
